# watch vs useState in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I started to learn React. In wy `tsx` file I have a function, inside there is a `useState` method to watch some values. And also there is a `watch` method to watch another values.

What is the difference between [watch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch/) and `useState` in React? I mean, let's say I have to watch a value in a textbox or combobox and react to its changes. What method should I use, `watch` or `useState`?

Here is the sandbox [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/watch-test?file=App.tsx)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const { watch } = useForm({ mode: 'all', reValidateMode: 'onBlur' });

  // this ?
  const [city, setCity] = useState<string>('Moscow');
  // or this ?
  const wcity = watch('city');

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing & look at the console how values changes :</p>
      {/* is there a way to watch city changes witout onChange in input:? */}
      <input value={wcity} defaultValue="any" /> <br />
      <label>{wcity}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How shoud I use `watch` or `useState` to log the changes of `city` (witout onChange method, if possible) ?

Comment: `react-hook-form` is not part of React. It is an entirely different library, and `watch` is an entirely different API than `useState`, which is a core React hook.

Comment: You can achieve whatever you want with `useState` and other core hooks provided by react, The `watch` might be a helpful hook in third party library to do the same stuff but with ease...

Comment: @Kartoos so, how can I use `useState` to log `city` changes?

Comment: You can use onChange listener, Any specific reason you would want to avoid it? Also if you just want to log the changes on `city` you can write `useEffect` and put `city` in depencencies list

Comment: @Kartoos, so, from what you say, neither useState nor watch are useful to log changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not see the changes neither in the `<label>` nor on the console while typing in the input in the sandbox provided by you, I looked at the documentation of [watch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) and here is the updated version which works:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const { watch, register } = useForm({
    mode: 'all',
    reValidateMode: 'onBlur',
  });

  // Will console the changes
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value, { name, type }) =>
      console.log(value, name, type)
    );
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [watch]);

  const wcity = watch('city', 'any'); // watch input tag registered with 'city' and put default value of wcity as 'any'

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing & look at the console how values changes :</p>
      <input value={wcity} {...register('city')} /> <br />
      <label>{wcity}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, the call for `register()` was missing in the tag and if you want to console the changes you need to write the `useEffect` as described in their documentation.

And finally if you want to achieve this without using any third party library then you can do something like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState<string>('any'); // default value for 'city' state is 'any'

  const cityChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setCity(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing & look at the console how values changes :</p>
      <input value={city} onChange={cityChange} /> <br />
      <label>{city}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Kartoos answer for `watch`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function App() {
  const { register, watch } = useForm({ mode: 'all', reValidateMode: 'onChange' });
  const cityValue = watch('city', 'any');

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('cityValue changed:', cityValue)
  }, [cityValue])

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Start editing & look at the console how values changes :</p>      
      <input name='city' defaultValue={cityValue} {...register('city')}/> <br />
      <label>{cityValue}</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```